# Criar diretórios em c++ com Linux

Tags: c, c++, linux, diretório, mkdir

Estou querendo criar um diretório na pasta home com c++, porem não existe uma maneira de fazer isso de maneira multiplataforma.
Eu descobri que na biblioteca "sys/stat.h" tem a função mkdir que cria diretórios, porem, alem do nome do diretório, a função precisa das permis ões do diretório. então eu fiz o código:

```
mkdir(nomedodiretorio.c_str(),0777);
```

Ele gera uma pasta, só que ele só da permissão de escrita pra mim e não para outros usuários. Já tentei todas as variações de 0777 e ele não gera uma pasta com permissões de tudo para todos. Qual o código correto ?

Comment: Atenção que `0777` é interpretado como octal e corresponde na verdade ao numero `511` em decimal. Já viu os parametros de permissões na [documentação](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir de [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), é possível efetuar operações com o sistema de arquivos de forma portável/multiplataforma, utilizando a biblioteca [`<filesystem>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem):

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path nome_do_diretório = "exemplo1";
    fs::create_directory(nome_do_diretório);
}
```

Se quiser criar diretórios recursivamente (e.g. `exemplo/de/dir/recursivo`), use `std::filesystem::create_directories`.

Se não tiver acesso a [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), você pode usar a [biblioteca equivalente de Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directory) (quase toda a API é equivalente com a que foi introduzida em C++, então é possível mudar de implementação sem praticamente alterar o código.)

Uma melhor maneira de passar as permissões corretas para o novo diretório é utilizar as permissões do diretório existente onde o novo será criado. Para fazer isso, passe o diretório cujas permissões serão copiadas como segundo argumento:

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path novo_dir = "exemplo1";
    fs::path existente_dir = ".";
    fs::create_directory(novo_dir, existente_dir);
}
```

No Linux, a cópia de permissões é equivalente ao seguinte código:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <sys/stat.h>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
  fs::path novo_dir = "exemplo1";
  fs::path existente_dir = ".";
  struct stat atributos;
  stat(existente_dir.c_str(), &atributos);
  mkdir(novo_dir.c_str(), atributos.st_mode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Em [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) não há uma maneira padrão de se fazer tal coisa. Porém, existe uma alternativa bem elegante para resolver o seu problema usando a biblioteca [`boost::filesystem`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html), que possui uma função chamada [`create_directories()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directories), que por sua vez é capaz de criar diretórios recursivamente, vejamos:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main( void )
{
    std::string dir = "foo/bar";
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    boost::filesystem::create_directories( dir.c_str(), ec );

    if( ec )
    {
        std::cout << "Erro criando diretorio '" << dir << "': " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Diretorio '" << dir <<"' criado com sucesso!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ g++ -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem teste.cpp -o teste
```